# Can someone tell me why my js timer isnt working?

Tags: javascript, html

**I really dont know what is happening**
I recently made this flask application and came across this error where my buttons don't works for other html table rows that are there and i don't know why. I tried my best to solve it but sadly couldn't. If someone can help me i would really appreciate it

HERE IS THE HTML CODE

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
  <style>
    body{

      background-color: khaki;
    }

    h1{
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size:5em;
      transform: translate(500px, 10px);


    }
/* 
     h4{
      font-family:monospace;
      font-size: 2em;
      transform: translate(700px, 10px);
    }  */
   div.container input[type=submit] {
 
    background-color:khaki; 
    border-radius: 1.8em 1.8em 1.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    color: black;
    border: none; 
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
    transform: translate(500px, 10px);
 
  
 }

 div.container input[type=text]{
  transform: translate(500px, 10px);
 }

  table th{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    transform: translate(500px, 10px);
  }
  table td{
   /* background-color: aqua; */
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 4px 8px;
   transform: translate(500px, 10px);
 }

  .btn{
    background-size: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 3em;
  }

  body{
    margin: 0;
  }
  .draggable{
    padding:1rem;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .draggable.dragging{
    opacity:0.5;
  }

  button.buttonReset{
    color: black;
    transform: scale3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  }
  .display{
    font-family: monospace;
  }
  button.buttonPlay{
    transform: translate(10px);
  }

  

  </style>


  <link rel="shortcut-icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico')}}">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Task Manager</h1>
    <br/>
    <form action="/my_timers" method="POST">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter New Task" name = "name" maxlength="10"> 
       <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-secondary" name="hello">
    
    </form>
    <br/><br/>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>TASK</th>
        <th>       </th>
        <th>       </th>
        <th>DONE</th>
        <th>TIME TAKEN</th>
        
      </tr>

      
    </table>
    {% for friend in friends%}
    <table>
      
      <tr>
        
        <td>
          <div class="container2">
          <p class="draggable" draggable="true">
          {{ friend.name }} <a href="/update/{{ friend.id }}" class="btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Update</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        </td>
        </p>
    
          
        </td>

        <td>
          <a href="/delete/{{ friend.id }}">
            <button class="btn"> <img src="static/7bdd1bc7db7fd48025d4e39a0e2f0fd8.jpg" alt="button" width="20" height="20" ></button>
            
          </a>

          <a href="/description">

            <button class="desbtn">+<button>
          </a>
        
          
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="stopwatch">
      
      <div class="circle">
        <span class="time" id="display">00:00:00</span>
      </div>

      <div class="controls">
        
          <img id="playButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/play-button_opkxmt.svg" />
        

        
          <img id="pauseButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/pause-button_pinhpy.svg" />
        

        
          <img id="resetButton" src="/static/download.png" />
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="static/new.js"></script>
    <!-- <table>
        <td>
          {{ friend.name }}
        </td>

    </table> -->
      
    {% endfor%}








  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

AND HERE IS THE JS:

```
const timer = document.getElementById('circle');

var hr = 0;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var stoptime = true;

function startTimer() {
  if (stoptime == true) {
        stoptime = false;
        timerCycle();
    }
}
function stopTimer() {
  if (stoptime == false) {
    stoptime = true;
  }
}

function timerCycle() {
    if (stoptime == false) {
    sec = parseInt(sec);
    min = parseInt(min);
    hr = parseInt(hr);

    sec = sec + 1;

    if (sec == 60) {
      min = min + 1;
      sec = 0;
    }
    if (min == 60) {
      hr = hr + 1;
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }

    if (sec < 10 || sec == 0) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
    }
    if (min < 10 || min == 0) {
      min = '0' + min;
    }
    if (hr < 10 || hr == 0) {
      hr = '0' + hr;
    }

    timer.innerHTML = hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

    setTimeout("timerCycle()", 1000);
  }
}

function resetTimer() {
    timer.innerHTML = '00:00:00';
}
```

The play button, pause button, reset button dont works for any other task that i add.
Please check

Comment: just pass the function name, don't send a string or timerCycle()

Comment: But it still gives me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: stopTimer is not defined

Answer (score 2):

So you do not keep track which timer you wanter to play.
I introduce you to classes.
I tried to keep most of your original code intact but I had to made some changes.

First change is as I said, using classes.
this code created a Timer object for each `.timer` element so it will be easier to keep track of each individual timer.

Second change is adding event listeners so clicking on buttons actually do something

Next is removing `sec = parseInt(sec);`. That is unnecessary beacause you dont have to keep track of leading 0 in this variable. You can add it just before displaying it for example in `printTimer()` method.

```js
class Timer
{
    timer = null;
    hr = 0;
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
    stopTime = true;

    constructor(timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.setListeners();
    }

    setListeners = () => {
        this.timer.querySelector('.playButton').addEventListener('click', this.startTimer);
        this.timer.querySelector('.pauseButton').addEventListener('click', this.stopTimer);
        this.timer.querySelector('.resetButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.stopTimer();
            this.resetTimer();
        });
    }

    startTimer = () => {
        if (this.stopTime === true) {
            this.stopTime = false;
            this.timerCycle();
        }
    }

    stopTimer = () => {
        if (this.stopTime === false) {
            this.stopTime = true;
        }
    }

    resetTimer = () => {
        this.hr = 0;
        this.min = 0;
        this.sec = 0;
        this.printTimer();
    }

    timerCycle = () => {
        if (this.stopTime === false) {
            this.sec += 1;

            if (this.sec === 60) {
                this.min += 1;
                this.sec = 0;
            }
            if (this.min === 60) {
                this.hr += 1;
                this.min = 0;
            }

            this.printTimer();

            setTimeout(this.timerCycle, 1000);
        }
    }

    printTimer = () => {
        const displayHr = this.hr < 10 ? '0' + this.hr : this.hr;
        const displayMin = this.min < 10 ? '0' + this.min : this.min;
        const displaySec = this.sec < 10 ? '0' + this.sec : this.sec;
        
        this.timer.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = displayHr + ':' + displayMin + ':' + displaySec;
    }
}

const timers = document.querySelectorAll('.timer');

timers.forEach(timer => {
    new Timer(timer);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: khaki;
    margin: 0;
}

button.buttonReset {
    color: black;
    transform: scale3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
}

button.buttonPlay {
    transform: translate(10px);
}

.display {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
    <div class="circle">
        <span class="time display">00:00:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <img class="playButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/play-button_opkxmt.svg"/>
        <img class="pauseButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/pause-button_pinhpy.svg"/>
        <img class="resetButton" src="/static/download.png"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="timer">
    <div class="circle">
        <span class="time display">00:00:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <img class="playButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/play-button_opkxmt.svg"/>
        <img class="pauseButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/pause-button_pinhpy.svg"/>
        <img class="resetButton" src="/static/download.png"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="timer">
    <div class="circle">
        <span class="time display">00:00:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <img class="playButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/play-button_opkxmt.svg"/>
        <img class="pauseButton" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/https-tinloof-com/image/upload/v1593360448/blog/time-in-js/pause-button_pinhpy.svg"/>
        <img class="resetButton" src="/static/download.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No you dont understand the problem is if i add a task to the table and time it, it works but the timer starts on the first task

Comment: Got it. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.